# Migrating Wordpress from DreamHost to Azure Wordpress Resource via UpdraftPlus "wp_options table does not exist..." error

Tags: database, migration

**Goal**
Our goal is to migrate a wordpress site from DreamHost to an Azure Wordpress resource.

**Process and Errors**
We installed [UpdraftPlus](https://updraftplus.com/) (pro version) on both builds. We utilized it's *[Send a backup to another site](https://updraftplus.com/how-to-migrate-a-website-to-another-server-using-updraft-migrator/)* -> *[Recieve a backup from a remote site](https://updraftplus.com/how-to-migrate-a-website-to-another-server-using-updraft-migrator/)* feature. During the database restoration it failed and gave the following error `wp_options table does not exists...`.

We ended up downloading the database back up file from [UpdraftPlus](https://updraftplus.com/). The top portion looked like this:

```
# WordPress MySQL database backup
# Created by UpdraftPlus version 2.16.27.24 (https://updraftplus.com)
# WordPress Version: 5.5, running on PHP 7.4.2 (Apache), MySQL 5.7.28-log
# Backup of: http://example.com
# Home URL: http://example.com
# Content URL: http://example.com/wp-content
# Uploads URL: http://example.com/wp-content/uploads
# Table prefix: wp_
# Filtered table prefix: wp_
# Site info: multisite=0
# Site info: end

# Generated: Tuesday 25. August 2020 19:52 UTC
# Hostname: mysql.example.com
# Database: `mydatabasename_com`
# --------------------------------------------------------
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40101 SET foreign_key_checks = 0 */;

# Table: `wp_options`
# Approximate rows expected in table: 551

# Delete any existing table `wp_options`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_options`;

# Table structure of table `wp_options`

CREATE TABLE `wp_options` (
  `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `option_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`),
  KEY `autoload` (`autoload`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=595049 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

# Data contents of table `wp_options`
 
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES 
  (1, 'siteurl', 'http://example.com', 'yes'),
  (2, 'home', 'http://example.com', 'yes'),
  (3, 'blogname', 'My Blog Name', 'yes'),
...
```

We took that script and used [Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to query the Azure MySQL database. Unfortunately it came up with the same error: `wp_options table does not exists...`.

The first command in the backup query script is to drop the current `wp_options` table (if it exists). The the following command is a create query that recreates the the `wp_options` table. This command silently fails. The next command, which inserts values into the `wp_options` table, is the one causing the error shown. There's no `wp_options` table for it to insert in to.

**Summary and Question**
Currently the MySQL create query is failing and causing an error. How do we transfer the database successfully?

Answer (score 1):

We downloaded a database back up via [UpdraftPlus](https://updraftplus.com/) from the Azure Wordpress. And the problem became pretty clear. Take a look at the *Storage Engine* and *Collation* of the create query:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_options` (
  `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `option_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`),
  KEY `autoload` (`autoload`)
) /*!50100 TABLESPACE `innodb_system` */ ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=214 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

On DreamHost, we edited every database table to have the same *storage engine* and *collation* as the Azure MySQL database tables. We just opened up good old phpMyAdmin and adjusted each table via table options, like so:

[image: phpMyAdmin wordpress table operations]

Just to be clear that's changing:
**Storage Engine**:
`MyISAM` -> `InnoDB`
**Collation**:
`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` -> `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

We then took a database export directly from phpMyAdmin and ran it through [Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). Viola! The whole database transferred succesfully.

**Actual Problem**
I'm not sure exactly why this wouldn't work initially, but... My speculation is the Azure MySQL database is in a Windows environment and the DreamHost MySQL database is in a Linux environment. So somewhere there are probably database configurations that don't line up.

Comment: Congratulations on your success.  View profile, Network profile for contact info, tips, free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.